# Can I get back unique guns I've sold in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

There are many unique guns in Borderlands, and when they don't look particularly useful I sell them. If I want to get them back, is there any way? Will the merchant I sold them to have them in his inventory?

This happened to me recently with Sledge's shotgun and I was hoping I could retrieve it somehow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you sell an item to a vendor, that item will be placed in a buyback list at the vendor. But, if you either quit the game, or leave the zone where you sold the items, this buyback list will reset itself, and the items will become unavailable.

There is also a cap of 20 items in this list, meaning if you sell 21 items, the first item you sold will be gone from that list.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Vending_machine#Buyback)